# Login as different user in identity server 4

Tags: identityserver4, openid-connect

I am trying to implement the LoginAs/Login as a different user feature using Identity Server 4. My Client Application is developed on top of Angular. I am trying to sign out the existing logged-in user and sign in the user using the provided userId. Maybe I am going the wrong way. Any solutions for that? Here is my code for Identity Server 4.

```
    [HttpPost("login-as")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> LoginAsAsync([FromBody] LoginAsViewModel model)
    {
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync();
        var user = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(model.UserId);
        if (user == null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }            
        await signInManager.SignInAsync(user,false);
        return Redirect("/connect/authorize");
    }
```

Comment: What OIDC flow is your Angular application using? Also, you are aware that `implicit` is effectively useless now and static-HTML-only SPA applications can't really work anymore...

Comment: It's Implicit flow

Comment: You're SOL then: with the changes to how browsers handle cookies and cross-origin requests over the past couple of years the `silentfresh` and single-sign-out features of OIDC and IS4 simply don't work anymore (as both features rely on cookies being exchanged for cross-origin requests through hidden iframes). You'll need to add a (thin) backend to the Angular app so the app uses `code`-flow instead of `implicit` flow.

Comment: Our other applications are written in code-flow. can we implement this with code-flow?

Comment: Yes, but only using back-channel, not front-channel (for the reasons I just described).

Comment: Thanks @Dai. I know it's too much to ask. Can you give me a small lead on how to implement ? or a sample project that you already know of

Comment: This is the official IS4 sample for `HybridBackChannel`: https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer4/tree/3ff3b46698f48f164ab1b54d124125d63439f9d0/samples/Clients/src/MvcHybridBackChannel

Comment: Thanks. I will try it out